# Remember form value when return back to submit due to some error

Tags: php

After filling the form when submit, accidentally due to some filling error ,the form is not submit and return to back,in this condition the value of all text box is blank. i want to stable value of all fields in this condition . I'm using php with smarty framework.  Please reply with solution as soon as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Smarty is not a framework but a template engine.

Comment: Post code. What have you already tried... etc, etc. People aren't just going to give you the code.

Comment: Please provide some code....?

Answer (score 2):

If the form is submitted to the page that contains it then you will have access to the submitted values, and can use them to populate your form. For example, if you are submitting the form via POST:

`<input name="something" value="<?=$_POST['something']?>" />`

If you are submitting the form to a different script, you could send the values back to the page with the form as URL parameters, or you could use temporary session variables, and unset them when the input passes whatever validation you are using:

```
$_SESSION["temp_something"] = $_POST["something"]; //In form processing script
```

Then in your form:

```
<input name="something" value="<?=$_SESSION['temp_something']?>" /> <!--In form-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the form fields, on the second round, by filling the content inside the value attributes of html tags, like so:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['test']; ?>" name="test">
```

Pay attention: this is a fast and simple solution. It gives you an idea. In good web programming practice you should sanitize the form data received by client in order to avoid security issues.